# Wrapping a function with an aych loop with a promise

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and still wrapping my mind around writing promises.

```
function addToList(data) {
    conversationList = data.Body.Conversations
    console.log(conversationList)
    for (i=0; i<conversationList.length; i++) {
        fullInbox.push(conversationList[i])
    }
    console.log(fullInbox.length)
}

var fullInbox = []
var maxLenReturn = 200
var offset = 0
function fetchData(offset){
    fetch(asynchCall)
    .then(response=>{return response.json()})
    .then(data=>{
        var fullLength = data.Body.TotalConversationsInView
        console.log(fullLength)
        addToList(data)
        if (offset < fullLength-maxLenReturn) {
            offset+= maxLenReturn
            fetchData(offset)
        }
    })
}

fetchData(offset) 
// trying to make something like this work
.then( .... console.log(fullInbox.length))
```

I have a loop inside the `fetchData` function and want to wrap it in a promise so that when its done, I can print out the `fullInbox`

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var fullInbox = []
  var maxLenReturn = 200
  var offset = 0
  fetchData(offset);
  resolve(fullInbox)
});

promise1.then(function(value) {
  console.log('promise resolved')
  console.log(value);
});
```

I think I need the `resolve` inside `fetchData` but unsure how to write it so that it will loop through everything before resolving.

Comment: `TotalConversationsInView` is from Exchange, edit your post and tags accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see of your code, your `addToList` function is synchronous, so it doesn't need to do anything with promises. But the next time you call `fetchData`, you need to handle the promise. So, something like this would work:

```
function fetchData(offset){
    return fetch(asynchCall)
    .then(response=>{return response.json()})
    .then(data=>{
        var fullLength = data.Body.TotalConversationsInView
        console.log(fullLength)
        addToList(data)
        let promise;
        if (offset < fullLength-maxLenReturn) {
            offset+= maxLenReturn
            promise = fetchData(offset)
        } else {
            promise = Promise.resolve();
        }
        return promise;
    })
}
```

And if you want to use the [async/await style syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await), things get a lot nicer to read:

```
async function fetchData(offset){
    let response = await fetch(asynchCall)
    let data = await response.json();
    let fullLength = data.Body.TotalConversationsInView
    console.log(fullLength)
    addToList(data)
    if (offset < fullLength-maxLenReturn) {
      offset+= maxLenReturn
      await fetchData(offset)
    }
}
```

Async/await is supported in all major current browsers, and you can polyfill for older browsers. Due to its cleaner syntax, I highly recommend using it. It will save you from writing bugs.

---

So, here is a shorter version, doing what you need it to do. It uses async/await. And each call to `fetchData` returns the inbox items from the offset it was passed all the way to the end. The use of default parameters allows you to avoid using global variables.

```
async function fetchData(offset = 0, maxLenReturn = 200) {
    let response = await fetch(asyncCall)
    let data = await response.json();
    let inbox = data.Body.Conversations;
    let fullLength = data.Body.TotalConversationsInView
    if (offset < fullLength-maxLenReturn) {
      offset+= maxLenReturn
      inbox.push(...await fetchData(offset))
    }
    return inbox;
}

let fullInbox = fetchData()
```

Comment: `fetchData(offset).then(response=>{console.log(response})` is returning empty, how do I return the `fullInbox`

Comment: Right...let me fix that.

Comment: Added an answer using async/await. I can add a pure Promises answer too, if you like, but this answer is much cleaner.

Comment: thank you! spent a ton of time today learning/practicing making asynch calls. This helped me understand them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps.

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
var fullInbox = [];
var maxLenReturn = 200;
var offset = 150;
for(let i = offset; i < maxLenReturn; i++) {
  fullInbox.push(i);
}
resolve(fullInbox);
}).then(value => console.log(value));
```